# Plugin tab not showing in typo3 backend

Tags: plugins, typo3

I've got an a question regarding typo3. I installed t3extblog from the extension manager within typo3.
Afterwards i wanted to follow the installation guide on this webpage:
[short installation guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/t3extblog/Installation/Quick.html)
Unfortunately I can't process step 4 since my typo3 is not showing the "Plugin" tab.

See this picture:
[Picture of "Web" -> "List" -> "Edit page"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTIDJ.png)

I couldn't find a proper hint to activate that tab until now.

Can anyone help please or explain how to process step 4 of the guide?

Answer (score 1):

The *plugin* tab cannot be found inside the page properties. You have to insert a **new Record** into your page.

The record has to be of type **Page content** (content element). The Content element itself can be of several types (Text, Images, HTML, Plugins...). You can change the Content types ('CType') in the *General* tab of your new Content element. There the CType 'Insert plugin' can be found.

When you change the CType, TYPO3 aks to reload the page. Afterwards, you get a new *Plugin* tab where you can choose plugins from any TYPO3 extension you installed.

Comment: Hello sebkIn, thanks a lot for your help. I followed your instructions successfully.